# Somar e dividir colunas o oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Possuo 4 colunas. Quero fazer o processo de subtração em 3 e dividir pela quarta.

Como faço essa operação no BD Oracle?

```
COLUNA1 - COLUNA2 - COLUNA3 = RESULTADO;

RESULTADO / COLUNA4 = COLUNA5
```

Comment: Simples `(COLUNA1 - COLUNA2 - COLUNA3) / COLUNA4`. Se quiser a coluna das somas faça `select COLUNA1 - COLUNA2 - COLUNA3, (COLUNA1 - COLUNA2 - COLUNA3) / COLUNA4`

Answer (score 0):

Se quiser retornar o resultado diretamente na consulta sql a sintaxe seria a seguinte:

```
select (COLUNA1-COLUNA2-COLUNA3)/COLUNA4 AS Resultado 
  from SUATABELA
```

Se necessário realizar a operação em um bloco/procedimento Pl/SQL a sintaxe seria

```
declare
  vColuna1 number;
  vColuna2 number;
  vColuna3 number;
  vColuna4 number;
  vResultado number;
begin
  select COLUNA1, COLUNA2, COLUNA3, COLUNA4 into vColuna1, vColuna2, vColuna3, vColuna4
    from SUATABELA
   where ID = :CHAVEPK;

  vResultado := (vColuna1 - vColuna2 - vColuna3) / vColuna4;
  dbms_output.put_line(vResultado);
end;
```

Comment: Cuidado se a coluna4 for zero , dará um erro de divided by zero , faça (case when coluna4=0 then null else (col...) end)